# Is there a way to use select.one on bs4 with the "or" function

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So basically i want to fetch data, and more specifically extract a text, from a website but the problem is that the thing that i want to search changes location.I'm sorry if i explain this badly,i just started learning python.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
url_patra = ("https://weather.com/el-GR/weather/today/l/a8c1d5fa8f854f3e5c626109483f1542b6eb8f29924330ccc44ffc07e3050bd7")
html_patra = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url_patra).content, 'html.parser')
patra_prediction =  html_patra.select_one("div[class*=CurrentConditions--phraseValue--2Z18W]").text
print (patra_prediction)
```

My problem is that sometimes it works with :

```
patra_prediction =  html_patra.select_one("div[class*=CurrentConditions--phraseValue--2Z18W]").text
```

and sometimes with :

```
patra_prediction =  html_patra.select_one("div[class*=CurrentConditions--precipValue--3nxCj]").text
```

I can't change everytime this specific line. So my final question is: Is there a way to use "or" function or something similar so that when the 1 line doesn't find the desired .text it uses the 2 line?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script to extract from that webpage what you need.

Location, weather, type of ....

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page_content = requests.get("https://weather.com/el-GR/weather/today/l/a8c1d5fa8f854f3e5c626109483f1542b6eb8f29924330ccc44ffc07e3050bd7").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content, 'html.parser')


def find_location():
    locator = 'div.CurrentConditions--header--27uOE h1.CurrentConditions--location--kyTeL'  # CSS locator
    item = soup.select_one(locator).string
    print(item)


def find_weather():
    locator = 'div.CurrentConditions--primary--2SVPh span.CurrentConditions--tempValue--3a50n'
    weather = soup.select_one(locator).string
    print(weather)


def find_weather_type():
    locator = 'div.CurrentConditions--phraseValue--2Z18W'
    type_of = soup.select_one(locator).string
    print(type_of)


def info():
    locator = "div.CurrentConditions--precipValue--3nxCj span"
    info_text = soup.select_one(locator).string
    print(info_text)


def as_of_time():
    locator = "div.CurrentConditions--timestamp--23dfw"
    as_of = soup.select_one(locator).string
    print(as_of)


find_location()
find_weather()
find_weather_type()
info()
as_of_time()
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no 'or' function.

as per the page source, I could see it is the current location.

Mostly the name of the location should be there.

if missed use null value validation while doing the extraction.

```
  if (html_patra.select_one("div[class*=CurrentConditions--phraseValue--2Z18W]").text) is null:
        loc = "No location"
  else
        loc = html_patra.select_one("div[class*=CurrentConditions--phraseValue--2Z18W]").text
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can't change everytime this specific line. So my final question is:
> Is there a way to use "or" function or something similar so that when
> the 1 line doesn't find the desired .text it uses the 2 line?

#### Good to know

`[attr*=value]` represents elements with an attribute whose value containing the substring value - So there is not really a need to handle it conditonal.

#### How to fix?

You are close to a solution - Just drop the dynamic generated part of the `class`:

```
html_patra.select_one("div[class*=CurrentConditions--phraseValue]").text
```

**Note:** As alternativ try to select via a different attribute that will not change that frequently -> `html_patra.select_one('div[data-testid="wxPhrase"]').text`

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
url_patra = ("https://weather.com/el-GR/weather/today/l/a8c1d5fa8f854f3e5c626109483f1542b6eb8f29924330ccc44ffc07e3050bd7")
html_patra = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url_patra).content, 'html.parser')
patra_prediction =  html_patra.select_one("div[class*=CurrentConditions--phraseValue]").text
print (patra_prediction)
```

#### Output

```
Νεφελώδης
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using `try:` and `except:` method**

By testing a block of code for errors,if you are 100% sure that only these 2 locations are going to be the same and never change.

**Example:**

```
try:
   patra_prediction =  html_patra.select_one("div[class*=CurrentConditions--phraseValue--2Z18W]").text
except:
   patra_prediction =  html_patra.select_one("div[class*=CurrentConditions--precipValue--3nxCj]").text
```

Comment: This will only work if `html_patra.select_one("div[class*=CurrentConditions--phraseValue--2Z18W]").text` raises an exception. You could have an assertion there to use exception handling, or use a simple if.